# Properly deploy assets folder using a setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include folder in setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108840/include-folder-in-setup-project)

I have a VS2010 C# solution that uses a file structure like this:

/

/sources

/sources/[projects]

/Assets

/Assets/[multiple assets folders and files]

I'm trying to set up a setup project to deploy the assets folder to the application folder during installation.  However, the closest I've gotten was to create a post build event for one of my projects to copy the folder.  The thing is that the setup project doesn't take the postbuild copied folder into account when installing.

Can anyone point me to the right way of doing this?  Adding the assets folder to one of my project is not an appropriate solution because it actually copies the folder, creating two copies.  Thank you.

Comment: Your post is not very clear. Adding the folder to your setup project is the correct solution. But you mention two copies. What's the other copy? Who creates it and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following method:

right-click on the setup project, select View > File System

drag the assets folder on top of the Application's folder

And voilà!