# Visual studio app.config file database path for installed apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-installer

I am using local database in my app and when I generate installation file (By [Installer Package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects&ssr=false#overview)), after installing program it gives database path errors.

**Eample**

```
an attempt to attach an auto-named database for file....
//OR
The given path format is not supported
```

[image: one]

I've tried to edit database path in `app.config` file but it failed every time, By default my code line is like this:

```
<add name="SampleDatabaseWalkthrough.Properties.Settings.SampleDatabaseConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SampleDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And my app installing in `C:\Program Files (86)\App_Folder\Setup` *Please note that future users might install it in custom path so I need a way to get dynamic path of installed app*.

**My question is** How can I get app installed path to replace with this part `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SampleDatabase.mdf`?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData` method to change your mdf file path.

Since, I don't know how do you published the winform project.

I recommend that you use Clickonce to publish it.

**First**, please include your mdf file in your project.

**Second**, you could try the following code to change the installed path after you published it.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
                {
                    string path = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory; //Get installed path
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);//set the DataDirectory 
                }
            }
```

**Finally**, based on my test, I can get the information from the mdf file after I publised it and installed it in another computer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer (specially including image). About `Form1_Load()` isn't it better if I put it in `Program.cs` file `static void Main()` function? because my app first opens login form and then form1 (PS: login form will be closed on successful login) that's why I said if i put it in `main()` function. What do you suggest?

Comment: Oh and currently my DB file is not in any folder (screenshot) https://ibb.co/f2NMbKq would that be ok? or I must put it in folder?

Comment: @mafortis, If you want to want to access the file in the app directly after published, you could try the code 'ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory;'. Also, I have changed my code in my answer.

Comment: I am using package installer (visual Studio extension) to create setup file. Should I also add db file manually in my setup files or it will be automatically included?

Comment: @mafortis, based on my research, it is necessary for you to add the db file in your setup files manually. You could refer to the link [Include folder in setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108840/include-folder-in-setup-project).

Comment: Hi, I've tried accepted answer in your link but I couldn't find any file system in view `View" > "File System`

Comment: @mafortis, you can look at this picture  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxGmS.jpg to find add the folder .

Comment: So I just select my mdf file there?

Comment: 1- Should I make any changes in my mdf file before putting it there? 2- what if later I update my database file, should copy it again or it will get updates automatically?

Comment: No comment on my question?

Comment: @mafortis, I think your problem may be solved in [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects&ssr=false#qna). You could ask a new question here.

Answer (score 0):

In production mode `|DataDirectory|` refers to 'bin' directory, not 'app_data'. If you placed the `.mdf` file in the `app_data` directory, you can change it like this:

`|DataDirectory|\SampleDatabase.mdf` to `|DataDirectory|\app_data\SampleDatabase.mdf`

```
<add name="SampleDatabaseWalkthrough.Properties.Settings.SampleDatabaseConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\app_data\SampleDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Update1:**

I'm sending some code. I just want to give you an idea. You can change it for your situation.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsExist())
    {
        CreateDatabase();
        CreateTables();
    }
}

// Create the Database
private void CreateDatabase()
{
    string basePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    string mdfFile = "TestDatabase.mdf";
    string ldfFile = "TestDatabase_Log.mdf";
    string mdfFullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(basePath, "Data", mdfFile);
    string ldfFullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(basePath, "Data", ldfFile);

    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");
    string str = "CREATE DATABASE TestDatabase ON PRIMARY " +
            "(NAME = TestDatabase, " +
            $"FILENAME = '{mdfFullPath}', " +
            "SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%)" +
            "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
            $"FILENAME = '{ldfFullPath}', " +
            "SIZE = 1MB, " +
            "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
            "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";


    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
    try
    {
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            myConn.Close();
        }
    }
}

// Create the tables and other stuff that you want
private void CreateTables()
{
    string conStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data\TestDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    string str = @"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
                    (
                        [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                        [Test] NVARCHAR(50) NULL
                    )";

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
    try
    {
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            myConn.Close();
        }
    }
}

// Check if there is the database
private bool IsExist()
{
    string basePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    string mdfFile = "TestDatabase.mdf";
    string mdfFullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(basePath, "Data", mdfFile);

    return System.IO.File.Exists(mdfFullPath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, and I have same question for you as I asked Jack, do I have to copy my mdf file to my installer? Should I make any changes in that mdf file before I copy it (if it's required to be copied)? TBH this is my first attempt and I'm absolute newbie so I need like step by step guidance to make it work (as I explained in my bounty description). Thank you

Comment: It's no matter. You can copy it or make it at the first run if it's not exist. And you don't need to change anything.
I think the problem is in the `path`, not in the file format or anything else.

Comment: Let say I don't copy my db file, can you guide me how to generate one at first run? Maybe that fixed my problem

Comment: Are you using `Microsoft SQL Server Database file` data source?

Comment: I think so (I don't know the long name of it as you mentioned it) but the file it creates is `.mdf` format and it is offline (local). I am not using any online database for this.

Comment: If you are using ORMs like Entity Framework, you can [configure it to make database if it not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355481/auto-create-database-in-entity-framework-core). If not, you can create your database at the first run.
Just look at this [helpful example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/create-sql-server-database-programmatically)?